# TypeScript - Get function parameters from key in array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that takes as arguments two keys of a specific object inside an array. The keys are the following:

- A string used to index a specific object
- A function (from which I need the types of its parameters)

The array of objects is the following

```
const obj = [
  {
    name: "number",
    func: (foo: number) => foo,
  },
  {
    name: "string",
    func: (foo: string) => foo,
  },
  {
    name: "array",
    func: (foo: string[]) => foo,
  },
];
```

And this is my approach

```
type SingleObject = typeof obj[number];
type Name<T extends SingleObject> = T["name"];
type FuncParams<T extends SingleObject> = Parameters<T["func"]>;

const myFunc = async <T extends SingleObject>(
  name: Name<T>,
  params: FuncParams<T>
) => {
  // Do something
};
```

I thought that when calling `myFunc` passing `"array"` (for example) as the first parameter, it would identify the object in question and correctly assign the parameters of the other key (which in this case should be `Parameters<(foo: string[] => foo)>`)

This is clearly not the case, as I can do the following without any problems

```
myFunc("number", ["fo"]); // Should only allow a number as the second parameter

myFunc("string", [34]); // Should only allow a string as the second parameter

myFunc("array", [34]); // Should only allow an array of strings as the second parameter
```

**Reference**

- [TypeScript Playground of the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Qe8Fe2E+wLBMIBkNhtWcyNanV6uOkY1mxFgRGlw3tZNJMzLJHp+18rMuqnu9g4IA)

Comment: `Parameters<T["func"]>` results in a type of `number | string | string[]` for `params` in this case, since all `T["func"]` does is aggregate all the types of the given array.  Thats why it works.  Now how to get it to work how you would like it to is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the compiler will infer the type of a string-valued property as `string` and not a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"number"`.

```
/* const obj: ({
    name: string; // oops
    func: (foo: number) => number;
} | {
    name: string; // oops
    func: (foo: string) => string;
} | {
    name: string; // oops
    func: (foo: string[]) => string[];
})[]    
*/
```

In order for your plan to possibly work, you need to convince the compiler that you care about the actual literal value of the `name` property of your elements of `obj`.  The easiest way to do this is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on `obj`'s initializer:

```
const obj = [
  {
    name: "number",
    func: (foo: number) => foo,
  },
  {
    name: "string",
    func: (foo: string) => foo,
  },
  {
    name: "array",
    func: (foo: string[]) => foo,
  },
] as const; // <-- const assertion
```

And now the type of `obj` is:

```
/* const obj: readonly [{
    readonly name: "number";
    readonly func: (foo: number) => number;
}, {
    readonly name: "string";
    readonly func: (foo: string) => string;
}, {
    readonly name: "array";
    readonly func: (foo: string[]) => string[];
}] */
```

where the `name` fields are the required types `"number"`, `"string"`, and `"array"`.

---

Next, the best way to have the compiler infer the type of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter is to give the compiler a value of that type from which to infer it.  That is, inferring `T` from a value of type `T` is straightforward, but inferring `T` from a value of type `T["name"]` is not.

So my suggestion is something like this:

```
/* type NameToParamsMap = {
    number: [foo: number];
    string: [foo: string];
    array: [foo: string[]];
} */

const myFunc = async <K extends keyof NameToParamsMap>(
  name: K,
  params: NameToParamsMap[K]
) => {
  // Do something
};
```

The type `NameToParamsMap` is a helper object type whose keys are the `name` fields from `obj` elements, and whose properties are the parameter lists from the associated `func` field.  Then `myFunc` can infer the generic type parameter `K` from the value of the `name` parameter passed in.  Once `K` is properly inferred, the compiler can check the `params` parameter to make sure it matches.

---

Of course you don't want to write `NameToParamsMap` by hand; you can make the compiler compute it from `typeof obj`:

```
type NameToParamsMap = { 
  [T in typeof obj[number] as T["name"]]: Parameters<T["func"]> }
```

Here I'm using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over each element `T` of `typeof obj[number]`, and using `T["name"]` and `T["func"]` to produce the keys and values of the object.

---

Let's make sure it works:

```
myFunc("number", [1]); // okay
myFunc("number", ["oops"]) // error
// -------------> ~~~~~~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

myFunc("string", [34]); // error
myFunc("array", [34]); // error
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBA7glgLgFgewK4zAYwQOwM6oIbbYCmATjFFmALABQtGOqCARgFYBcYAFAN61gCwmPAFsinXCSiYA5gG5+ggGZJMaTlyUIEnTEhHNSASjABeAHxD9hkgpoBfMAB8wfGoKGjxYSdPmKBFTUNLR0fGClZEwtwyP8HZ1cAzzEJCL87DyD1blC0uIBtAF1oy19ZYrt7I2LaWhBgOpoGXDAWVjMwAsU3D2FUsAAiPQNSQYAaZOyQ7V1rYzNLUMn3MHsVgV7Bfu9B8pkJqdUczVnYv1KwZcV1nuSdzkG8EhI8AE9D1cDjmbD94su11WtxoRTABHQWFwdlooEhjDabE4JCIeAAJlgADZvLpbAQo9FYnEPIYjGyDTKCAkYzDYq4-XJnMkLGLM2y0dZJL5galElK7fYU5K82k46aMv7pKKLc6yKrjLkeEV0klPF7vIXc5VihmnSWFEoy-5FKpghpNGBvAAORDAADkvAAVBAABWeomwAFk8FbOjwuo6wNIwJabQglIjWAU2UUIY6CsMvIMikVOG7XmIYKRsAAeeODbLJyz2WHgUO2h1iZ3pj3e32mRXbeYkTgFPJWUYkE3Jfat9v7bvc56vN59s7GweOc10ZpQ1AiN4AMWOnQIbzUYBzAGkwEQAB5ZzBo7BgADWRDe4ftTtd7pEXp95i4ihJW42YCtd+wnErRGrX7rAotyKWhLi2YBgDAAARBAfAQTM4D8DkYRoBdlzULhhmbCYugARhKOQwAgtpT3eWg0OOTC2RwhNtCtbBkxMYjSBIBASFhSCAFpuJ43ieMsAA-IThI4sBHWtW0AHJ9kkoMT0wBB8EIKAZGEZhMVtGBYPLMBJLZSSmgojC9ilA4FQKABmAAWAiiMgli2PIpdKLVEcaOs2zmJeRyaCAA)

Comment: This is awesome, couldn't ask for a more detailed and comprehensive answer. Learned a ton from your examples and links to documentation. Thank you so much!!