# Get function parameter from key in array of objects - Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function which takes an argument called functionName. functionName should always be the value of "Name" property from an array of objects. I skimmed through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804714/typescript-get-function-parameters-from-key-in-array-of-objects) but I was not able to achieve what I am looking for.

This is what I have.

```
const data = [{
  Name: 'functionA',
  EntryPoint: false,
  SystemOrClient: 'Client'
}, {
  Name: 'functionB',
  EntryPoint: false,
  SystemOrClient: 'Client'
}, {
  Name: 'functionC',
  EntryPoint: false,
  SystemOrClient: 'System'
}] as const;

const getSystemInfo = (functionName: string) => { //functionName should only accept values of Name property
//...
}


getSystemInfo('functionA') //should pass
getSystemInfo('functionAB') //should fail while compiling
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the type of `data` with the `typeof` operator. This can be indexed with `number` to get a union of all elements which you can index with the `Name` property.

```
const getSystemInfo = (functionName: typeof data[number]["Name"]) => {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=72&pln=15&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3gKBjAOQQFsBTALhgHIAzAVzGCgEtwBBKgGjxgFEwoAJwCeABRDMBlGggA2EUt3wBlYdFLEA8oIDCs5qSnU9BgVRwBfTjFz4iZSrQZNWYAEJce-IWIlGZ8oo8qupauvqGUI4mkeZWNjz2FNT0jCzgOp743iLiklEwAQpKMCFQGtoxRlRlGnEAujAIEDCgkFAA3Dg4bdAwAOakULXEAJJgNCBoMAAUqS7gSZRQwgAOpCA08EgIGGB0xABGpIL1GABESef1AJRoAHw2Ft04g8Nq5WMTIDNOaa4cO4AeiBEAAFiA6LI4DBVs0IK8hiNxpNfvN0mA2B5gaCIVCYTJmLIYAB3MFE0itEDEVZEyT9IA)

Comment: Thanks. How do I still enforce an interface to the array of objects? I did readonly IData[] which converts the name to a string.

Comment: If you give `data` an explicit type, all information about the actual object you assigned to it will be lost. The only option is having a no-op generic function just for initialising the object.